# function key pressed javascript

Tags: javascript, key

I just can not understand the various steps of this function, who can explain them?

```
function keypress(field,e,x) {
    if (!e) {
        var e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.keyCode) {
        code = e.keyCode;
    }
    else if (e.which) {
        code = e.which;
    }

    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    console.log("Character" + character);

    if (code == 13) {
        box.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: If Enter is pressed, focus on `casella2`.

Comment: Very much broser-specific tests. e is not always defined, thats why you can get it via `windows.event` in that Browsers. `e.keyCode` and `e.which` is also Browserdependent. The `Sring-fromCharCode`-function takes the keyCode and returns the actual char to this keyCode. Then it prints that char to the console. When the keycode was 13 (which means "Enter"), casella2 should be focused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
}
```

If e (the event variable) is not defined, you set it to `window.event`. This makes sure you have the necessary data in the variable `e`.

```
if (e.keyCode) {
    code = e.keyCode;
}
else if (e.which) {
    code = e.which;
}
```

Browser specific tests; some Browser (as far as I know IE) uses `e.wich`, other browser use `e.keyCode`. This indicates which key was pressed by the user.

```
var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
console.log("Character" + character);
```

Converts the code to a char.

```
if (code == 13) {
    casella2.focus();
}
```

Checks if the enter key was pressed, if so, casella2 is focused.

You can find a list of the different keyCodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes).